# Should global static arrays be freed?

Tags: c, arrays, global

Say I declare a global array `int arr[10];` Should I free it somehow in the end?

Comment: You can't free an Array, you can't even free a Pointer. All you can free is that memory block where your Pointer points. How does your Array get Free'ed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not free it.You should use `free()` only when you have use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't free it and you don't need to. `arr` is in *static storage* which means that it is created on program startup and destroyed on program termination. Explicit freeing is neither possible nor required as the storage is automatically freed on program termination.